# Return results from array_search/ Array to string error

Tags: php

I am working on a program that allows a person to search for an order record(name, address, order amount) by entering in the customer ID and clicking a submit button. The array is loaded from a file that a previous screen creates.

What I am trying to figure out is how to echo all the contents for the record specified by the ID entered. I have only been doing PHP for a couple of weeks any help would be appriciated.

```
<?php

    $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $customers = file("customers.txt");
    $number_of_customers = count($customers);

    if($number_of_customers ==0) {
        echo "<p><No customers found.</strong></p>";

    }
    //$key = array_search('id',$customers); 
    $key = 'id';
    $search=array_search($key,$customers);
    echo $customers;


?>
```

Comment: You should use a database for this...

Comment: If you're forced to use a text file, how is information stored in that text file? Does it follow some pattern?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Passerby pointed out you *need* to be storing this information in a database  of sorts. The fact that this is customer information makes the need for a database that much more significant.

Now, in terms of "echoing" data .. what problems are you having? You can do just what you are doing now and echo plain text or you can wrap the text in an element and style it via CSS.

### Database

IF you decide to go the database route (and hopefully you do) you could run a simple query to retrieve all of the customer information you want by passing an ID:

```
"Select * From Customer Where customer_id = ?"
```

Just an example of the simplicity ...

Now to answer your question:
You're right about not using the function properly. `$customers` is the array, so your value is going to be stored in the `$search` variable that you have setup.

Thus:

```
$search = array_search($key, $customer);
echo $search;
```

Also, check out the documentation for the function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: I agree with the database, this project just requires a text file(i'm guessing for beginner purposes). The issue I am having is displaying the entire record based on the user id entered. it is not returning anything, and I am getting an array to string conversion error. which I am assuming is the (echo $customers;) at the end is not formatted correctly.

Comment: @user2168066 I've updated slightly to give you some insight on how to use array_search